# storing large integer consisting of zeroes and ones

Tags: c, arrays, binary, integer, scanf

I am stuck at a question where i have to read an integer D such that D follows the following rules:

-> D contains only zeros and ones

-> 1 ≤ Length of the number D ≤ 10^5.

-> D may begin with zero

And further, I have to store this number in array such that each digit of the no is stored in one cell of the array.

for example, if the number is `001011` it should be stored in the array like

```
arr[0]=0  arr[1]=0  arr[2]=1  arr[3]=0  arr[4]=1  arr[5]=1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If so, then please tag with this language.

Comment: you have done good job. Use `for` loop to iterate over index and save each digit. to know more read about `for` or `while` loops in `C` language

Comment: the problem is that D is an INTEGER and it can be read only once i.e it is read in one go.So there is no point of an index for a number

Comment: `D contains only zeroes and ones` - that sounds strange. Are you sure you got that part of the assignment correct?

Comment: @imyjalil character by character, with a resize loop algorithm via `realloc` to expand as you read more digits of `D`. You described *exactly* what to do for the rest. Eventually you'll reach a non `{0,1}` value in your input stream (or EOF) and that's where you stop. Alternatively, you could just allocate a 100K buffer (its not that huge), slam all the `char` values in, translate them from char `'0'` and `'1'` to `0` and `1`, shrink to the buffer to fit, and be done with it.

Comment: @4386427 ,yes! I haven't fully described the problem because whatever i posted here is just a part of it.and I am unable to proceed  with this particular part. :)

Comment: @WhozCraig ,can you show me the implementation if you don't mind?

Comment: To me this is still unclear. How do you get the value of `D`? No standard integer type can have length 10^5. Do you read D as a string (aka char-by-char) from stdin (or a file)?

Comment: @4386427 that's the point. No standard integer types can hold a value with 100,000 digits. That's why the digits are being stored in an *array*. It's basically a poor-mans binary big-number representation.

Comment: @imyjalil - Did you solve the first sub task where D <= 50?

Comment: @imyjalil - You are on the wrong path. Solving that problem doesn't require that you store the individual digits. Just have two counters counting the number of zeros and the number of ones. Read the input one char at the time.

Comment: @4386427,how do i do that ,because D is a number and it is read in one go

Comment: @Elyasin No.Actually my problem is that Iam unable to read the input properly

Comment: No, D is not a number read in one go. D is input from stdin (or a file). You can read the digits one-by-one in several ways. One way is to use `scanf("%c", &someChar);` if input is from stdin.

Comment: @4386427 , can you please demonstrate how digits can be read one-by-one?

Comment: @WhozCraig, why don't use one of the multiprecision opensource libraries at will?  Then you'll be able to operate with that number also.

Comment: @LuisColorado Because the problem is from a coding proficiency website like codechef.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is known as an XY problem (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The real problem (as you linked in a comment) doesn't require storing digits of D. Instead just count the number of ones and zeros.
 Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    int rc;
    char c;
    int numZero = 0;
    int numOne = 0;
    while(((rc = scanf("%c", &c)) == 1) && (c == '0' || c == '1'))
    {
        if (c == '0') 
            ++numZero ;
        else
            ++numOne;

        printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Zeros: %d Ones: %d\n", numZero, numOne);
    return 0;
}
```

> Input:
>
> 111000111
>
> Output:
>
> 111000111
>
> Zeros: 3 Ones: 6

Now you can do some logic on the counters to find out if the actual output shall be "Yes" or "No".

Good luck.

Comment: No need for being embarrassed :-)

Comment: @4386427 Please update the question. As it stands the answer doesn't make sense with the given question. The discussion in the comments should be edited and added to the question.

Comment: @imyjalil Please update the question. As it stands the answer doesn't make sense with the given question. The discussion in the comments should be edited and added to the question.

Comment: @2501 - Agree, the question asks for Y but really needs X. So the Q->A is a bit of a mess.